# how often should emacs 28.1 native compile basic emacs files?

Tags: native-comp

I installed 28.1 from source, and when I load emacs in daemon mode, it native-compiles everything under `/emacs-28.1/lisp/`. Is this normal behaviour? Shouldn't this only need to happen once?

The only config i have set is to move the eln-cache into my non-standard `/.emacs.d/` location,
with `(setq native-compile-target-directory (concat user-emacs-directory "eln-cache"))`.

Comment: It *should* only happen once, yes.  Does your problem happen if you *don't* move the eln-cache to a "non-standard location"?  It might not be related at all; but at the same time, your question reads a little bit like "I'm bleeding and all I've done is stab myself", so maybe test that and report back?

Comment: @phils thx for the prod, and also for the should, helpful to know. looks like it is due to my config.

Answer (score 0):

So my stabbing myself to bleed config is the culprit, even though it shouldn't be:

`(setq native-compile-target-directory (concat user-emacs-directory "eln-cache"))`

leads to native-comp comping and comping till it can't comp no more, then just a little more, then starting again.

Comment: Maybe that's a configuration item for `early-init.el`? Just a wild guess: I haven't tried it out.